# What can make value in theme variables be empty by template render?

Tags: theming

I have one site with a theme that has a page.vars.php where there are various assignments like `$variables['content_column_class'] = 'classname'` and by the time the `page.tpl.php` tries to `print $content_column_class`, there is no value.

This same theme is in another site without this issue. What can make the value in theme variables be empty by template render? Is there something in the database? I've run `drush cc all`, I've run the update.php, all with no change. What methods for debugging these type of issues can I take?

Comment: check for custom modules

Comment: It's the same set of custom modules. Is there some line of code that I can look for? What can unset those variables?

Comment: Is the function name in page.vars.php correct for your new theme name?

Comment: Yes, the function name is correct. So I just saw this happen on a site that was working that no longer is working. The only change was to a view and a feature. There is something getting clobbered somewhere and I don't know where to go to clear it out.

Comment: Move everything from `page.vars.php` into template.php to simplify the issue